# How to insert data from one table into another table?

Tags: python, mysql

I'm new to python and I was trying to insert data from one table to another and the code is executing but it is not reflecting any changes in new table in which I want to insert data.

```
import mysql.connector
conn=mysql.connector.connect(user='root',password='',host='localhost',database='xyz')
mycursor=conn.cursor()
mycursor.execute("insert into newTable select * from oldTable  group by mac,date,time order by mac")
```

Comment: Hmm, `select * from ... group by ...` is weird for a sql query. Did you control that it does when you want in a interactive SQL session? And anyway, a session should always be closed with a `commit`...

Answer (score 1):

I suppose it is because you are not committing the changes. Use the below code and see if it works.

```
conn.commit()
```

You need to use conn because that is the variable name for your connection to the database. A commit must be sent to the server, which in turn will commit your changes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add commit() to make the changes.

```
conn.commit()
```